# Emacs as an editor (as opposed to VIM)

Tags: vim, emacs

I recently started using emacs as an everyday environment, half because I always wanted to gain the perspective of "the other side," and half because I'm forced to at work :P. Its been a week and I can definitely see the advantages of using emacs and what it means to "live inside emacs." The buffers are very convenient and just the ability to search through the buffer as if it is an editor is amazing. Emacs has been my "shell" since the day I started it last week.

However, when it comes to editing code, I am still not convinced that I should use emacs as opposed to vim. I don't know if it is because I am too used to vim, but with emacs to move around text I always need an extra key, such as 'M-f' instead of 'w,' or 'C-f' instead of 'l'. Is this just a learning curve that I have to overcome?

I am not trying to start a flame war, I would just like some perspective. Thanks!

Comment: Such questions are off-topic on [so] and everywhere else on the network. However, it [has been asked before](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/986/vim-vs-emacs-and-no-this-is-not-a-flame-war), possibly several hundred times before that too. So that link should give you all the perspective you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I started with vim but left it many years ago for emacs.  I can say that it took me much longer to be converted to the baseline editing interaction (key combinations, non-modal, etc.) than it did to recognize the value of "living inside emacs," as you say.  So my advice would be to actually do the emacs tutorial (`C-h t`, yes it's *worth* it) to be sure you're really using the full power of emacs' baseline editing interactions, and give it a month to see if you're converted organically.  If not, then give each [`vim-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VimMode) and [`viper`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ViperMode) a try.  If you're still not converted then do your code editing in vim.  :-)

But the most salient point here is do *not* jump to `vim-mode` or `viper`, give it a good long while to see if you can enjoy emacs editing interaction without introducing more emacs add-ons which might have weird interactions with other emacs add-ons.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that distinguishes vi (and gvim and nvi and all the other vi clones) is that it's modal.  That means that when you're not in edit mode, you can use single letters as commands.  Other editors, like emacs, don't have modes, so a single letter with no modifier is usually just inserted into the buffer.  That's why commands in emacs need to have modifiers.

Comment: false.  Emacs has a plethora of modal "VI" emulation modes, which are mentioned elsewhere in this thread.

Comment: @event_jr did you even read what you typed?